# sequelize subquery as field column in where clause nodejs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have endpoint which have `search` and `description` as get params.

And I need to make query like this in sequelize but got problems.

Query:

```
SELECT brands.*, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products WHERE brand_id = brands.id) as productCount
    FROM product_brands as brands
    WHERE 
        (brands.name LIKE '%$search%' OR (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products WHERE brand_id = brands.id) LIKE '%$search%')
        AND
        description LIKE '%$description%';
```

My Sequelize:

```
    const where = {
      [Op.and]: [],
    };

    if (query.search) {
      where[Op.and].push({
        [Op.or]: [
          { name: { [Op.like]: `%${query.search}%` } },
          { [Sequelize.literal('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE products.brand_id = ProductBrands.id)')]: { [Op.like]: `%${query.search}%` } },
        ],
      });
    }

    const brands = await ProductBrands.findAndCountAll({
      where,
      attributes: {
        include: [
          [Sequelize.literal('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE products.brand_id = ProductBrands.id'), 'productCount'],
        ],
      },
      limit,
      offset,
      raw: true,
    });
```

And got error like this:

```
Unknown column 'ProductBrands.[object Object]' in 'where clause'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Sequelize.where` in order to use `Sequelize.literal` in `where` conditions:
replace

```js
{ [Sequelize.literal('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE products.brand_id = ProductBrands.id)')]: { [Op.like]: `%${query.search}%` } }
```

with

```js
Sequelize.where(Sequelize.literal('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE products.brand_id = ProductBrands.id)'), Op.like, `%${query.search}%`)
```